# Redirect port on Windows from loopback to outside

Tags: sockets, networking, portforwarding

I have a socket that listen on port 6100 on my development machine, whose lan address is 192.168.1.2

I can access the socket and use it with the address 127.0.0.1:6100, but I can't access it from 192.168.1.2:6100 (I need to access the socket from another client on the Lan)

If I type netstat -an | find "6100" on the command prompt I get:

TCP    127.0.0.1:6100         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

So I need to redirect all calls to 192.168.1.2:A_RANDOM_PORT to 127.0.0.1:6100

How can i do that?

I tried with:

netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=6200 listenaddress=192.168.1.2 connectport=6100 connectaddress=127.0.0.1

But without luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally been able to accomplish this task, but only using an external tool.

I downloaded "PassPort port forwarding utility" and set up a redirection from 192.168.1.2 to 127.0.0.1

Unfortunately I haven't been able to do that without an external tool.

Answer (score 0):

You failed to post the code concerned, but you bound your listening socket to 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0. Just fix that. No oort forwarding required.

Comment: I can't bound the socket to 0.0.0.0.... The "real" socket is on an Android emulator, so it is bound on 127.0.0.1 because the ADB port redirection bounds it there.. and I haven't found a way to change that..